# JRE 1.5 to 1.6 Issue on Macbook Pro

Tags: eclipse, macos, java

I'm running Mac OS X 10.5.8 and have been trying over the past couple of hours to upgrade to Java 6.  In doing this, I hope to change my Eclipse JRE to 1.6 so I can properly sync with my group's repo.

So far, no dice.  I've downloaded every update I could find on Apple's website, and checked Java Preferences over and over.  Not only is Java 6 not even there, the window that pops up looks nothing like the one detailed on Apple's website or any of the "upgrade to 1.6" tutorials I've found online.

I am now at a bottleneck: is this an Eclipse problem?  I don't think so, since my OS X seems to be pooping itself, but I'm fairly sure there are literally no more updates for me to even try and install.  Argh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest way to configure runtimes, or JREs, is using `Applications/Utilities/Java Preferences.app`. The order defined here controls which version is used by browsers.

The command line utility `/usr/libexec/java_home` will show the current default version. Well-behaved scripts should be using the result of this command over the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

If you did an upgrade you also might have to [manually change your JDK pointer](http://memerocket.com/2009/08/06/upgrade-os-x-10-5-8-to-jdk-1-6/).

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
sudo rm -fr CurrentJDK
sudo ln -s 1.6 CurrentJDK
```

If if you try all this and you still only have a 1.5 install, remember that 1.6 is only supported on hardware that is Intel and **x64** compatible. This affects some of the first MacBooks that included an Intel chip.

Comment: I have an early model Macbook Pro, from mid-2006, with an Intel Core Duo processor...This means I can only run 32-bit code, which in turn means I cannot update to 1.6 correct?  I would pull out serious amounts of frustrated hair if this were the case...

Comment: It's the perfect excuse to get a new MBP! It does appear that [your model](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/stats/macbook_pro_2.0.html) has a 32-bit processor and can't run Apple's Java 6. However, you should checkout the [SoyLatte project](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/); it's a port of OpenJDK so you can run Java 6 on 10.4 and 10.5.